# Hadoop name node fails to load in VirtualBox after sometime

Tags: apache, hadoop, ssh, hdfs, namenode

I've configured and am running **Hadoop v2.7.2** along with **OpenJDK v7 u191**. Once the configuration is done, all the process namely name node, data node, secondary name node, etc. runs perfectly (Checked with *jps*).

I'm running **Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS** in Oracle VirtualBox (*Currently VirtualBox is running in Windows10*).

Once the system is halted (or shut down) for some time, then after restarting Hadoop, name node fails to start. All other processes other than name node is working fine, yet the name node is not.

I've tried reinstalling and reconfiguring the whole thing from the scratch, yet the problem is like it was. Also, I would like to add that there was no error when Hadoop was installed along with other software. I have also tried to reformat HDFS, but that doesn't work either.

I'm new to Big Data and Hadoop, so it would be very helpful if anyone could tell me what exactly is wrong and how to solve it step-by-step.

*One more thing, someone previously advised me to configure SSH server to run hadoop properly, so I'd configured SSH server along with.*

> **This is what Happens, when I restart my Ubuntu after sometimes**
>   [Image: Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF5XF.jpg)

Comment: Kindly update your post with namenode logs

Comment: I do not get any error while starting Hadoop using start-dfs.sh & start-yarn.sh, all the process normally starts without an error except the name node.

Comment: Post `hadoop-zenith-namenode-dpramanik-virtualbox.out` file logs